# Sum of Cosines is $-1$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Using this formula, 
$$z^k-1=(z-1)(1+z+z^2...+z^{k-1})$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
How can we prove the following,
$$
cos(\frac{2\pi}{k}) + cos(\frac{4\pi}{k}) + ... + cos(\frac{2(k-1)\pi}{k}) = -1
$$

Comment: _Hint_: $z=e^{2\pi i n/k}$. Now consider the real parts.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel how do i convert the equation in term of cosine to complex

Comment: de Moivre's law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $$
I= 1+e^{i \frac{2\pi}{k}} + e^{i \frac{4\pi}{k}}+ ... + e^{i \frac{2(k-1)\pi}{k}}= \frac {(e^{i \frac{2\pi}{k}})^k -1}{e^{i \frac{2\pi}{k}} -1}
=0
$$

Thus, with $\cos x=Re(e^{ix})$,

$$
\cos\frac{2\pi}{k}+ \cos\frac{4\pi}{k}+ ... + \cos\frac{2(k-1)\pi}{k}= Re(I-1)=-1
$$